# Substring replacement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

I have fields like this table in mysql database,

```html
<table border=1 ><tr><td>No</td><td>Value</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>System Code id(19032809128); unique list system</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>System Code id(526371576351726); unique list system</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>System Code id(162837120831092); unique list system</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>System Code id(31-329-103912); unique list system</td></tr>
</table>
```

can someone tell me, how to remove only this string part "id(.....);" where values in id is not same every fields. remove with mysql query.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of desired result ?

Comment: MariaDB has `regexp_replace()`.

Comment: remove this part of string, "id(...);" in all columns. with short command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be somthings like this

```
select No, concat( 'System Code  (',Your_value_column , ') unique list system' ) as Value
 from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do with php

```
   echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>No</th>
  <th>Value</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['No'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Value'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange requirement; after you get rid of that information, every line will be identical except for the value under heading `No`.  Here's a query that will do that (though I don't see why you'd want to):

```
select No, 'System Code  unique list system' as Value from table where 1;
```

Latest word from SO is that [regex replace is not a function in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql).  So your alternative, if you want to do a true regex replace, is to use php/python/etc.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a function to do regular expression replacement.

Here's an example of a query that does the specific example in your question. But if you have other cases (like multiple replacements to make in a single string), this will have to serve as a guideline.

```
SELECT no, CONCAT(
   SUBSTRING(value, 1, LOCATE('id(', value)-1), 
   SUBSTRING(value, LOCATE(');', value)+3)) AS value
FROM mytable;
```

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/825b02/3)

It would be easier to do this in any programming language that supports regular expression string replacements. For example, fetch the string as is, and do the replacement in PHP.

---

Here's an example:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT no, value FROM mytable");

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $no = $row["no"];
  $value = preg_replace("/id\\([0-9-]+\\); /", "", $row["value"]);
  print "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$value</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: how can I do it with PHP, can you give me reference